# Enable AWS Batch in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-batch

I am working in the US-East-1 (N.Virginia) and have even configured the Default Region Name to `us-east-1` using the command `aws configure`.

But I am not able to access Batch using CLI. Batch is not even listed as one of the Available Services in `aws help`.

Any ideas how to enable Batch in AWS Cli? I have administrative access in IAM console so permissions don't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch service is relatively new, so its commands only exist in fairly new versions of the aws CLI.

Commands for batch in the latest cli documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/index.html?highlight=batch

If you are running Windows, simply download the updated installer.  https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

If you are using OSX or Linux use pip.  `pip install --upgrade awscli`

Comment: Thank you so much. Upgrading aws cli using pip enabled Batch.

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu's apt repository have the latest aws cli? I had done a fresh install with apt.

Comment: The Ubuntu repositories often contain fairly old packages, particularly for packages with political problems (ie. not free, not gnu, relatively new, not _linux_).  It would be highly unusual for the package manager to have a current version of aws cli.